# AWS S3 max file and upload sizes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

AWS S3 documentation says:

> Individual Amazon S3 objects can range in size from a minimum of 0
>   bytes to a maximum of 5 terabytes. The largest object that can be
>   uploaded in a single PUT is 5 gigabytes.

How do I store a file of size 5TB if I can only upload a file of size 5GB?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadingObjects.html) you should use multipart uploads:

> **Upload objects in parts—**Using the multipart upload API, you can upload
>   large objects, up to 5 TB.
>
> The multipart upload API is designed to
>   improve the upload experience for larger objects. You can upload
>   objects in parts. These object parts can be uploaded independently, in
>   any order, and in parallel. You can use a multipart upload for objects
>   from 5 MB to 5 TB in size.

[Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html) there is a list of the APIs and an example on how to use each one.

Comment: It looks like the 5GB limit is when uploading objects in a single operation. For files > 5GB, multipart upload needs to be used. thanks.

Comment: And then the maximum size of each part is 5GB.  The minimum size of each part is the greater of 5MB or total object size ÷ 10,000.  (So a 5TB file must be uploaded in parts of size between 500MB and 5GB).

Comment: Just to state the obvious, but at 5GB per part, it would be 1000 parts that would need to be uploaded.