# Problem with Streaming large files with Boto3 to S3 on ec2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to stream large files from HTTP to S3 directly.
I rather not download the file and then stream it, i  am trying to do it directly.
so the source is big file(60GB) that is to be streamed from http server, the dest is s3 bucket.

i have tested on two envoirments:
on my WSL env, when memory gets to 100% the script gets killed, setting max_concurrency to 2, nothing really helps, why the heck i still get memory overload?

on Ec2 (micro) machine, which is where i want to run the code, the boto code does not even run or show any error ? maybe i need to increase the memory of machine from 1GB to 2-3 ?
but i still would like to keep it on free tier...

Is there anyway to stream such large files directly ?
when i stream small files, like 1GB or less, its working without a problem..

i think the problem is with memory issues, that the code trys to read the http file into memory and upload, maybe the way is to read it into memory in chunks and stream in chunks ?
how i do it, i am not python expert.. been working on it for days..

```
    def stream_to_s3(self, source_filename, remote_filename):
        error = 0
        self.log(f"====> Streaming {source_filename} to S3://{remote_filename}")

        s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
        bucket = s3.Bucket(self.params['UPLOAD_TO_S3']['S3_BUCKET'])
        destination = bucket.Object(remote_filename)

        with self.session.get(source_filename, stream=True) as response:
            GB = 1024 ** 3
            MB = 1024 * 1024
            max_threshold = 5 * GB
            # if int(response.headers['content-length']) > max_threshold:
            TC = TransferConfig(multipart_threshold=max_threshold, max_concurrency=2, multipart_chunksize=8 * MB, use_threads=True)
            try:
                destination.upload_fileobj(response.raw, Config=TC)
            except Exception as e:
                self.log(f"====> Failure streaming file to S3://{remote_filename}. Reason: {e}")
                return 1
        self.log(f"====> Succeeded streaming file to S3://{remote_filename}")
```

Comment: That's a lot of work you're doing just to avoid saving 60GB to disk (which is not a particularly huge file). After all, the EC2 instance is downloading the file anyway.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43021420/758174) help? For more than 5GB object you must use multipart upload.

Comment: If you don't want to download the file, store it in EFS, instead of S3. Then you can access it from any instance, container, lambda, directly without a need to download it.

Comment: @Marcin Should note that generally EFS can be either very slow or very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [smart-open](https://pypi.org/project/smart-open/) package to obtain file objects for input sources and output destinations. This should enable "efficient streaming of very large files".

```py
from smart_open import open

remote_uri = f's3://{remote_filename}'

with open(remote_uri, 'w') as f_out:
    # Assuming requests library.
    for line in response.iter_lines(): 
        f_out.write(line)
```